# LabVIEW Tutorial with Serial Connection

Tags: serial-port, labview, serial-communication

Does anyone know where a good LabVIEW Tutorial on Serial Connections (RS232).
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty straightforward example:

http://www.ni.com/white-paper/2897/en

Answer (score 0):

There are some complete apps in the Example directory. First of all, make sure that you don't have any hardware issues and check your serial port settings in OS configuration.

I hope you know that you can test your RS232 communication by connecting the Rx directly to the Tx pin.